# How to use OAuth 2.0 protocol using SpreadSheetService in android app

Tags: android, spreadsheet

I am trying to get data from a spreadsheet in google Drive but i have to turn on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps in order to avoid OAutha Authentication but obviously is less secure

So how do i implement it , cause i got Invalid Credential error when i try to use my account

```
    spreadsheet.setUserCredentials("GmailAccount","Password");
```

the erros i got

```
       com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
```